# How to config proxy in openSUSE 13.1

Tags: proxy, opensuse

I need connect to internet by proxy server. I edit KDE and YAST proxy settings but nothing works. I try to manually edit /etc/sysconfig/proxy. Same config works good on my working computer under Windows 7 but on my notebook undes SUSE can't.
My proxy server is proxy.tellur.local that works on port 8080.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At start my brain not understand that i use local proxy server. So i run command nslookup on Windows computer and add line in my /etc/hosts file with ip address and url of local proxy-server i want to use. After this changes internet works fine.